# How to get data-list value in next page post method

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

here i am using data-id and value this working fine ,but no w i want pass the value for next page(home.php).in this page i want display data-id value how can do this, i am trying like (**echo '';**) this but always i am not getting

```html
<form action ="test2.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:1px;">
 <input list="options" type="text" class="form-control options" style="border-radius:0px;height: 46px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City">
  <datalist id="options">
   <option data-id='1' value='A'></option>
   <input type="hidden" value='1'>
   <option data-id='2' value='B'></option>
   <input type="hidden" value='2'>
   <option data-id='3' value='C'></option>
   <input type="hidden" value='3'>
   <option data-id='4' value='D'></option>
   <input type="hidden" value='4'>
  </datalist>
</div> 
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

test2.php

echo print_r($_POST);//Array ( [location12] => D ) 1

Comment: Any errors? I don't understand the question.

Comment: i want pass the data-id value in next page

Comment: Using `data-??="value"` is a way to get data to javascript not move it around between forms. You will have to either SESSION it, or use hidden inputs

Comment: @ RiggsFolly see my updated code i am trying like this but if am selecting d means  i want to display the value 4 but here displaying 1